# VS Code 1.58: Why always two Terminals (Integrated Terminal and Workbench Panel)?

Tags: julia, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for learning the Julia language. With the recent ver 1.58, VS Code now supports Terminal to be moved/opened in the Editors area ([Visual Studio Code June 2021](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_58#_terminals-in-the-editor-area)). I like this feature because it saves me screen space.

However, whenever I run my Julia script (using Ctrl+F5, Run Without Debugging), I always get two Terminals opening: one window within Editor Area and the second within the Workbench panel. The script output appears on the Terminal window within the Editor Area, but the Terminal window is blank in the Workbench panel.

My question is: Is there a way to turn off (disable) the Workbench panel from automatically opening whenever I run my program?

Thank you.